# AutoIT failing to run a Dll function which is successful from compiled C++

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to call `WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx` from a dll using AutoIT, but I keep running into errors.

I've verified the call does not fail if done in the following C++ code:

```
LPSTR fname = (char*)"BPAuto";
HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("wtsapi32.dll");
channelopen = (channelopenFunc) GetProcAddress(mod, "WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx");
HANDLE hnd = channelopen(WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, fname, 0);
```

that is, I get the correct resulting handle `hnd` which is not NULL.

When I attempt the same in autoit, it does not work though:

```
$dll_handle = DllOpen($path)
; The handle is valid, @error is 0
$handle=DllCall($dll_handle, "handle", "WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx", "dword", 0xffffffff, "lpstr", "BPAuto", "dword", 0)
; handle is 0, @error is 1
```

What's the difference between those / why does the second one fail?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `lpstr`, use the autoit type `str`:

`$handle=DllCall($dll_handle, "handle", "WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx", "dword", 0xffffffff, "str", "BPAuto", "dword", 0)`

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DllCall.htm
[image]